# Spring, hal browser and entities relationship

Tags: spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have two entities, Post:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Post {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String date;
private String content;
private String imageUrl;

@ManyToOne
private User author;
@ManyToOne
private User owner;
```

and User:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

private String email;
private String address;

private String avatarUrl;
private String about;
private Boolean active;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "author")
private List<Post> authorPosts;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
private List<Post> ownerPosts;
```

I am using HAL Browser to add Post and User but I have problem with relationships.

Let say I add user and link to that user is https://localhost:8080/users/1 and I add post https://localhost:8080/posts/1

Should I update field author of https://localhost:8080/posts/1 and add link of user/1 ? I am not sure but it is impossible in hal browser.
Or should I add https://localhost:8080/posts/1 to List in User entity?

When I want to add to that list I have sth like that:
[image]
What should I paste here? Link to that post?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to update the `author` field of `Post` entity. You can do that by sending a `PATCH` request on post endpoint as below:

```json
PATCH /post/1
{
  "author": "http://localhost:8080/user/1"
}
```

I haven't used HAL browser much, but I expect this request should work same way.